# Confused by when clauses in algorithm section

Tags: modelica

```
model try
  Real x(start = 1);

algorithm 
  when x >= 7 then
      reinit(x, 5);
  end when;

equation
      der(x) = 1 ;

end try;
```

The `when` statement should be triggered whenever the guard condition is changed from false to true.
But it is not the case in OpenModelica. The example `try` in OpenModelica showes that `when` is triggered only once. I was wondering whether it is the bug of OpenModelica or some misunderstanding from my side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.  I am pretty sure this would be a bug in OpenModelica.  The model works as you would expect in Dymola 2013.

My guess is that it is related to the fact that your when condition involves `x` and the statements inside end up changing `x` (the same variable).  It may be that it somehow fails to notice the reinit in the monitor function used to determine the point at which the when clause should trigger.

Comment: This was indeed a bug in OpenModelica[1], due to no event iteration being made for algorithm reinit. From the time I reported it until it was fixed, it took 4 hours.
  [1]: https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/1830